# Haystack haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor not indexing new objects

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a Haystack/Elasticsearch/Django setup and registed the setting:

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

New objects however are not being indexed, forcing me to run manage.py to update the index. Is this the correct behavior or am I missing another part of the puzzle? Been through the docs numerous times.

I also tried attaching a post_save listener to the Django model signal with:

```
connections['default'].get_unified_index().get_index(YourModel).update_object(your_instance)
```

Comment: Can you verify if the `post_save` handlers are actually executed?

Comment: Yep it is being called. Bombed it with an exception, and it was raised.

Comment: Maybe you can show us more of your model/index definition?

Comment: Yes, show us your models and indexes. I am facing the same problem. Maybe I can add something to the discussion inserting here some experiments that I am testing.

Comment: @MauricioAbreu - I ended up giving up and using pyelasticsearch directly which got the job done much simpler.

Comment: @AidenBell thank you for this I'm having the exact same problem I will move to pyelasticsearch